# List all shell functions, excluding private functions that start with either one or two underscores (e.g "_func" or "__func”)

Tags: r, bash, function, shell

I use this alias to list all functions:

`alias ls-funcs='compgen -A function'`

Small example of the result:

```
__youtube_dl          # Two underscores.
_add_composure_file   # One underscore.
search                # My function, No underscores.
```

Out of these functions, "search" is mine, the others are builtin/private functions,
how would one exclude these builtin/private functions and just list my own user functions?

Comment: `either one or two underscores` so start with one. A function that starts with two also starts with one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not depend on R-base's `compgen` and be compatible with either Bash, Ksh or Zsh:

```sh
alias ls-funcs=$'typeset -f | awk \'BEGIN{FS="("}/^[^_[:space:]{}].*\(\)/{print $1}\''
```

A bit longer but slightly more robust:

```sh
alias ls-funcs=$'typeset -f | awk \'match($0,/(^[[:alnum:]\-:][[:alnum:]_\-:]*)[[:space:]]*\(\)/,m){print m[1]}\''
```

Answer (score 2):

Pipe to `grep` to exclude names beginning with `_`.

```
alias my-funcs="compgen -A function | grep -v '^_'"
```

Comment: @5c0tt I thought you were listing shell functions. like `typeset -F | awk '$3 ~ /^[^_]/{print $3}'`